# Sharepoint 2010 web part & IE 11 - targets document mode 8... APIs may not be available

Tags: 2010, web-part, content-editor-web-part, internet-explorer, ie-11

I am running some javascript (d3.js, sp.js) in a web part on a sharepoint 2010 site. Everything runs fine when I use chrome or firefox, however when I open the page in IE 11 it does not load correctly and I see the warning:

`The attached page targets document mode 8. Some console APIs and features may not be available`.

I've tried using the emulator as IE 10 or Edge, but then nothing loads. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks!

Update:

I added compatibility mode and emulate IE 10, however it errors at `AllItems.aspx`, `Unable to set property 'outerHTML' of undefind or null reference`. If i click play through, everything loads ok.

Comment: IE 11 must be run in Compatibility View mode. SharePoint 2010/2013 does not support IE 10/11 native/Edge mode.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Thanks for the heads us. I added my site to the compatibility list, but now when I load the site I see a large pause icon and the debugger errors: `Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference'. The line that errors out is not part of my code so I assume it is part of sharepoint. (edit: that is if i enable intranet sites. if I just add to microsoft compatibility lists nothing changes and I receive the same error)

Comment: I would try to reproduce that error on a page that has zero customizations of the same site template (Team, Publishing, etc.). This should help you determine if you're getting that error from custom code or not.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Oh that would be logical. All my other sharepoint pages load fine, so I'm thinking it might be an issue loading the sharepoint API, sp.js? Is there something I can do to further investigate this?

Comment: also weird, after I turned both compatibility settings on, when I first navigate to my page I receive the original: `attached page targets document mode 8. some console api's may not be available`, but if I then reload the page that is when I see the large pause button and `innerHTML of undefined or null reference`

Comment: ok update: editing any page works, but editing any page with dev tools open causes an error. sometimes: `unable to get property 'childNoes' of undefined or null reference`.
These errors occur in `AllItems.aspx`, however on my specific page I am also receiving errors on `d3.min.js` and `jquery.js` - `Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that Sharepoint 2010 was forcing IE11 to render in IE8. I ended up changing the master file (`v4.master`) for the specific sharepoint site and editing the `<meta>` to default to `IE=10`. It did not affect the other sharepoint sites within my larger sharepoint site, and seems to be working. Thanks, Trevor, for the lead!